# jQuery UI Autocomplete Responce Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am having some trouble accessing the JSON data provided by a script for an autocomplete box, and was wondering if anybody could help.

This is the Javascirpt code which deals with the autocomplete box:

```
$(function() {
             $("#student_search").autocomplete({
                  source: "functions/find_student.php",
                  delay: 100,
                  minLength: 1,
                  select: function(event, ui) {

                      student_result = ui;

                      $('#student_search').val(student_result[0].label);
                      highlightStudent(student_result.label, student_result.value.id, student_result.value.house);
                  }
            }); 
         });
```

And an example of the response is:

```
[{"label":"larry winkles","value":{"id":1,"house":"s"}}]
```

I am struggling to find out how to access that data when it gets sent back to the success part of the autocomplete code. Specifically when I click on the name, the error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined
```

Thanks for any help.

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried like this :

```
select: function(event, ui) {
   var label = ui.item.label;
   var value = ui.item.value;
}
```

Let me know for any concerns.

Comment: Thanks, but just like everything it returns [Object  object] as the result.

EDIT: It turns out that it DOES work, but for some reason its setting the text box value to [Object object] and having everything else work perfectly normally! I check I am not using any assigned variable names or anything but I am certain that im not.

Anywayy, this is a new problem so ill say thanks and give it a bit of a go to fix :)

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I have a doubt about the nature of the ui variable, may be you can check it by using `console.info(ui)` if you were on Firefox.

I suppose that the problem is in line :

```
highlightStudent(student_result.label, student_result.value.id, student_result.value.house);
```

replace :

```
student_result
```

by :

```
student_result[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however it sadly gave me the same error :(

Comment: If the variable ui is of  Type String then you can transforme it into an array by `student_result =  eval(ui);`

Comment: The variable UI is of tpye JSON data, from a json_encode($result); php line.

Comment: `json_encode($result);`  returns a string representing the json data. After all, it is of type String. You have to parse it so to get  a javascript representaion of JSON data. The code may be something like this :`var myObject = eval("(" + myJSONtext + ")");`